# Book series read 20+ years ago. At least 4 books. Each title included a person's name and then a gemstone, like 'Owen's Opal' (not a real title)

Tags: story-identification, books

It's a sci-fi story where this guy travels to different worlds and saves them. All I specifically remember is that on each world he goes to, the people had differently shaped ears; I think in the last book I read, they had square ears. By the fourth book, the story was getting a bit redundant, but I still wanted to find out how things turned out.

I remember the title of the last book I read was 'BLANK's Opal' (just gotta fill in the blank). It was a name that began with an O. Anyone know what I'm referring to?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. How did the main character travel from world to world? A spaceship? Portals? Something else?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the [Adventures of Kelvin of Rud](https://www.goodreads.com/series/40493-kelvin-of-rud) series by Piers Anthony and Robert E. Margroff.

The books are:

- Dragon's Gold
- Serpent's Silver
- Chimaera's Copper
- Orc's Opal
- Mouvar's Magic

So the book you remembered had "Opal" in the title is *Orc's Opal*. The books do indeed dwell unnecessarily on the shapes of people's ears.

Comment: Well, the first book did have the crux of it being that Kelvin was unusual compared to most people on the world he lived on, being a round ear among people with pointed ears.

Comment: If so it would be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/220052/looking-for-a-book-about-out-of-body-experiences-and-entering-dragons-minds/220062#220062

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Having the same answer does not make two questions the same.

Comment: @Feathercrown: except that [that is the policy for story-identification questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3376/23243). If they have the same accepted answer, then they are duplicates.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots It may have been the same book but I read the other question and had no recollection of any of the details that they provided.. I had only a very vague memory of the story.. I couldn't even remember the protagonist's name! so while it may be a duplicate answer, I would never have realized it was the same by the previous question.. sorry if I broke a rule.. it's my 1st time asking a question..

Comment: @AsylemKat you haven't broken any rules :-) We quite often get several questions asking about the same book because different people remember different things about the book. The reason we link the questions together by marking them as duplicates is so people searching for a book can easily see all the questions about any particular book. It **doesn't** mean yours was a bad question!

Comment: @John Rennie I do believe you are correct! I was sincerely hoping the ear detail would be enough to identify it because that's about all I really remembered! Thank you so very much! I can't wait to reread this! (And maybe actually remember it this time! )